# При запуске программы выдает ошибку, как ее исправить?

Tags: delphi

Выходит табличка со следующим текстом:

> `Project Project1.exe raised exception class EInvalidOperation with message 'Cannot focus a disabled or invisible vindows'. Process stopped. Use Step or Run to continue.`

```
const
 R: array[1..13] of string[2] =
 ('I', 'IV', 'V', 'IX', 'X', 'XL', 'L', 'XC', 'C', 'CD', 'D', 'CM', 'M');
 A: array[1..13] of Integer =
 (1, 4, 5, 9, 10, 40, 50, 90, 100, 400, 500, 900, 1000);

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  mode:integer;
  Radix1,Radix2:integer;
implementation

{$R *.dfm}

//===================== Вспомогательные функции ============================

function CharToInt(Ch:char):integer;
begin 
  case Ch of
    '0'..'9': Result:= Ord(Ch) - Ord('0');
    'A'..'F': Result:= Ord(Ch) - Ord('A') + 10;
     else Result:= 0;
  end;
end;

function IntToChar(N:integer):char;
begin 
  case N of
    0..9   : Result:= char(Ord('0') + N);
    10..15 : Result:= char(Ord('A') + N - 10);
    else Result:= '0';
  end;
end;

//===================== Основные функции ================================

function StringToInt(const S:string; Radix:integer):integer;
var i:integer; 
begin
  Result:= 0;
  for i:= 1 to Length(S) do
    Result:= Result*Radix + CharToInt(S[i]);
end;

function IntToString(N,Radix:integer):string;
begin 
  while N > 0 do begin
    Result:= IntToChar(N mod Radix) + Result;
    N:= N div Radix;
  end;
end;

function RomanToArabic(S: string): Integer; 
var i, p: Integer;
begin
 Result := 0;
 i := 13;
 p := 1; 
while p <= Length(S) do 
begin
while Copy(S, p, Length(R[i])) <> R[i] do
 begin
 Dec(i); 
 if i = 0 then
 Exit;
 end;
Result := Result + A[i];
p := p + Length(R[i]);
 end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
if Edit1.Text='' then
StaticText2.Caption:=''
 else
StaticText2.Caption:='По русски -> '+IntToStr(RomanToArabic(Edit1.Text));
   RadioGroup2.Enabled:= Length(StaticText2.Caption) > 0;
  Edit2.Clear;
  RadioGroup2.ItemIndex:= -1;
end;

procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
Key:=UpCase(Key);
  case Radix1 of
    2 : case Key of '0'..'1',#8,#13 : ; else
    begin if (Mode=0) and (not (Key in ['0'..'9','I','M','D','C','L','X','V',#8])) then
 Key:=#0;
 if (Mode=1) and (not (Key in ['0'..'9',#8])) then
 Key:=#0;
 if (Mode=2) and (not (Key in ['I','M','D','C','L','X','V',#8])) then
 Key:=#0; end; end;
    8 : case Key of '0'..'7',#8,#13 : ; else begin if (Mode=0) and (not (Key in ['0'..'9','I','M','D','C','L','X','V',#8])) then
 Key:=#0;
 if (Mode=1) and (not (Key in ['0'..'9',#8])) then
 Key:=#0;
 if (Mode=2) and (not (Key in ['I','M','D','C','L','X','V',#8])) then
 Key:=#0; end; end;
    10: case Key of '0'..'9',#8,#13 : ; else begin if (Mode=0) and (not (Key in ['0'..'9','I','M','D','C','L','X','V',#8])) then
 Key:=#0;
 if (Mode=1) and (not (Key in ['0'..'9',#8])) then
 Key:=#0;
 if (Mode=2) and (not (Key in ['I','M','D','C','L','X','V',#8])) then
 Key:=#0; end;  end;
  end; 
end;

procedure TForm1.RadioGroup2Click(Sender: TObject);
var N:integer;
begin
  N:= StringToInt(StaticText2.Caption,Radix1);
  case RadioGroup2.ItemIndex of
    0: Radix2:= 2;
    1: Radix2:= 8;
    2: Radix2:= 10;
    3: Radix2:= 16;
  end;
  Edit2.Text:= IntTOString(N,Radix2);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Radix1:=10;
  RadioGroup2.ItemIndex:= -1;
  Edit2.Clear; StaticText2.SetFocus ;
end;

end.
```

Comment: @SpiridAndrey, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: @SpiridAndrey Уточните ошибку.

Comment: @SpiridAndrey, извините конечно же, но неужели вы и правда так хреново знакомы со средой Delphi7 и английским языком в целом?

     Project Project1.exe raised exception class EInvalidOperation with message 'Cannot focus a disabled or invisible vindows'. Process stopped. Use Step or Run to continue.

Вам же черным по белому пишут, что корень ошибки -

     'Cannot focus a disabled or invisible vindows'

Да и к тому же, дебаггер в Delphi сразу после ошибки и последующим нажатием F9 **ВЫДЕЛЯЕТ СТРОЧКУ КОДА, ГДЕ ВОЗНИКЛА ОШИБКА СИНИМ ЦВЕТОМ.**

Answer (score 5):

```
StaticText2.SetFocus ;
```

перенесите в FormShow. в FormCreate еще некуда фокус ставить..